# Data not complete when export to Excel

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I've tried to export report to excel using *JasperReports* and *iReport*, but the result is that not all of the data can be shown in *Excel*, whereas when I export it to *pdf*, it works fine. Here is my code :

```
JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.IGNORE_PAGE_MARGINS, true);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "\\report\\report1.xls");
exporter.exportReport();
```

The output in *Excel*:
[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: when i export the report into PDF, it works fine. But when i export it into Excel , some rows are missing like the image i've uploaded,

Comment: Did you test export to *xls* in *iReport*? Everything is fine?

Comment: yes, everything is fine when i preview it in ireport

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the placement of the columns, are there maybe spaces in between the columns or they may be overlapping, and it is always advised if you want your export as excel you should not give awkward spaces in the report for perfect fit. Same could be checked in the rows in the detail band, if there is overlap or not.

So give it try maybe it works.

thanks.